# How to get the date for 4th Friday of November in any year using Hive

Tags: hive

How to get the date of fourth Friday of November in any year in Hive? Month will always be 11 and day is 4th Friday.

Need to get the date for black friday analysis, where i need to find the dates for black friday in all the years from 1980 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

This code is calculating the date, filtering for November and fourth Fridays, and formatting the final output as "yyyy-MM-dd". Remember to replace your_database with your actual database name before running the query.

```
SELECT 
  year,
  date_format(date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('1970-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd') + 86400 * ((year - 1970) * 365 + leap_years(year - 1970))),
          6 * (floor((5 - weekday(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('1970-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd') + 86400 * ((year - 1970) * 365 + leap_years(year - 1970)))) / 7))) + weekday('1970-11-01')), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS black_friday_date
FROM years
WHERE month(date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('1970-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd') + 86400 * ((year - 1970) * 365 + leap_years(year - 1970))),
          6 * (floor((5 - weekday(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('1970-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd') + 86400 * ((year - 1970) * 365 + leap_years(year - 1970)))) / 7))) + weekday('1970-11-01'))) = 11
  AND dayofweek(date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('1970-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd') + 86400 * ((year - 1970) * 365 + leap_years(year - 1970))),
          6 * (floor((5 - weekday(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('1970-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd') + 86400 * ((year - 1970) * 365 + leap_years(year - 1970)))) / 7))) + weekday('1970-11-01'))) = 5;
```

Comment: This is not giving any output. Where in this code i have to change a database. I need the dates of 4th friday of november of every year.